# strange visibility scope behaviour in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, visibility

Have a strange behavior with scope visibility, and I couldn't find this in the manuals. 
So, here is the piece of my code simplified to the base.

```
from server import WWW_DOCUMENT_ROOT

def write_config(project_abs_path):
    print WWW_DOCUMENT_ROOT

    # WWW_DOCUMENT_ROOT = 'A'
```

In here, if the last line - the assignment - is commented out, `print WWW_DOCUMENT_ROOT` works fine and prints global's value. 
If assignment statement uncommented - `print WWW_DOCUMENT_ROOT` stops working and says `'WWW_DOCUMENT_ROOT' referenced before assignment`.

Obviously issue is fixed with `global WWW_DOCUMENT_ROOT` statement, but why it behaves differently depended on if the variable is to or is not to be assigned later in the code. That's shaky and unobvious, or I'm not getting something here. Why is it this way?

`python 2.7.3`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Short Description of Python Scoping Rules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any name you refer to in a function is considered a global, **until you assign to it**.

The compiler sees the assignment in the function and marks the name as a *local* variable instead. As a local name, `WWW_DOCUMENT_ROOT` has no value when you try to print it.

Use the `global` keyword if you wanted assignment to `WWW_DOCUMENT_ROOT` to affect the global variable:

```
def write_config(project_abs_path):
    global WWW_DOCUMENT_ROOT 
    print WWW_DOCUMENT_ROOT

    WWW_DOCUMENT_ROOT = 'A'
```